# How to simulate lossy power line on LTSpice?

Tags: simulation, ltspice, power-line-communication

I need to add lossy power line in LTSpice model to be able to simulate the signal transmission over this line.

This means that I will need two components:

- 230 VAC power source model
- asset power line model

Like that:

[image]

I did find ideal lossless transmission line model:

[image]

But this is not that I need. Is there any off the shelf solution?

If not: how do I build it my self?

Comment: Take a look at [this link](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~moon/ece323/hspice98/files/chapter_21.pdf). Might have to create your own for the particular situation. Look at the help included with LTSpice, it's pretty good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're simulating a transmission distance less than 1/10 of a wavelength (so less than 60 km for a 50 Hz signal), you should get reasonable results replacing the LTRA element with a single pi or T section. For example, for a pi section you could use this in place of your 1000 m line:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2W4fs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note: Values based on your [other question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/181590/ltspices-ltline-lossy-transmission-line-symbol-slowing-down-the-simulation-pr/)

If you want to increase the accuracy (or the length), you can simply use mulitple cascaded sections, making sure the total R, L, and C values add up to the right number and that they're evenly distributed along the line. It's also a good idea to try the simulation with, say, 1 and 2 sections and see that the result doesn't change very much, to verify that this approximation is good enough.

Comment: PS. Actually I'd keep your answer in ["slow simulation"](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/181590/ltspices-ltline-lossy-transmission-line-symbol-slowing-down-the-simulation-pr) question too. Or it is not good for some reason?